# Javascript array and if condition

Tags: javascript

I am having an array like this format

```
var aa = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

var categoryid = ["a","x","e","w","q","p"];
```

And I wants to check this list like this

```
for(var ii = 0; ii < aa .length; ii++){
iid += " && category != "+aa [ii];
}
```

Also I need to check condition like this,

```
if(categoryid != 0 iij) { 
    alert("value not present");
}
```

Here this condition is not working like this exactly. Here I need like this format

```
if(categoryid != 0 && categoryid != 'a') {
    alert("value not present");
}
```

Please help me..

Comment: Are you saying you want to check that `category.id` is not equal to any value within the array?

Comment: @dipesh, yes it is currect

Comment: what exactly you want to check and out of the above what is working and what not ?

Comment: What is with `iij` in the condition `if(categoryid != 0 iij)`? And also is it `categoryid` or `category.id`?

Comment: sorry did not recognise it

Comment: I wants to add this array condition dynamically. Is this possible?

Comment: Your edit just made things more confusing. Please describe what you want to do with words rather than code samples. It's really not clear what you're attempting. `categoryid` is not going to ever be equal to `0` or `'a'` if you set it equal to an array. Is that `if` test supposed to be inside the `for` loop? Are you trying to find values that are in both arrays? Are you trying to do something with values that are in only one array? Or...?

Comment: I am having 2 arrays. First array contains a-h and it is in sequential order. Second array contains a, x, e, w, q, p characters but it is not sequential order. It must check the given first array character is present or not in the second array using javascript.. plz help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a value is in an array (or, in this case, not in an array) using the array's `indexOf` method (assuming newer browsers).

Alternatively, try this shim:

```
function in_array(array,value) {
    if( array.indexOf) return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
    for( var i=0, l=array.length; i<l; i++) {
        if( array[i] == value) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to say that you want to test that `category.id` is not equal to any value within the array then you can use the [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if (categoryid != 0 && aa.indexOf(category.id) === -1) {
   alert("value not present");
}
```

Note that `.indexOf()` is not supported in IE8 and older, but MDN explains [how to work around that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Comment: @DipeshParmar That's just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't be so dynamic, what you need is like below:

```
if(categoryid != 0 && aa.indexOf(category.id) == -1) {
  alert("value not present");
}
```

Comment: It can be, when using `eval()` in one of its appearances.

Comment: @Sirko Yes, it can be. But we just don't use `eval()` :)

Comment: @Sirko - Friends don't let friends use `eval()`. (Actually I don't agree that `eval()` is _always_ a bad idea, but I really don't think it's appropriate here.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Sure, this is not a valid usecase for `eval()` (but there are some). I just wanted to correct the statement "it is not possible".